# What are the differences between the Flash Professional and the Flash Builder?

Tags: flash, flash-cs4, flash-builder

I couldn't find a comparation on the web, so, what's the difference between the Flash Professional and the Flash Builder?

**--update**

I saw in a video that I can edit some code in the Flash Professional. And I just saw coding in Flash Builder. So, my understand is that Flash Professional does what Flash Builder does, but not the oposite. Is it right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [Flash Professional](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash/) refers to the traditional Flash IDE that is a member of the Creative Suite family.
- [Flash Builder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashbuilder/) refers to the actionscript code editor built upon Eclipse (previously known as Flex Builder).

Comment: Flash Professional doesn't "do" what Flash Builder "does" (or vice versa)... however, there is some minor crossover in that they are both tools that enable designers/developers to compile swf's. Check out this link for a description of all the different technologies associated with the Flash Platform: http://www.adobe.com/flashplatform/

Comment: Another good explanation can be found [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/learn/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fd6.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fba).

Comment: I think this is the best explanation I have seen http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Flash-Professional-CS5-and-Flash-Builder-4

Answer (score 3):

Flash Builder: Flash Builder 4.7 software is a professional-grade development tool for rapidly creating games and applications for the web and mobile devices using ActionScript and the open source Flex framework. It includes support for intelligent coding, interactive step-though debugging, and multiplatform publishing workflows.

Flash Professional: Flash Professional is a timeline-based productivity tool for creating animated SWF and FLV content, used by creative professionals to add interactivity to websites. Flash Professional contains an ActionScript editor for basic ActionScript editing. However, for advanced ActionScript editing, most ActionScript developers use Flash Builder.

http://www.adobe.com/in/products/flash-builder/faq.html

Comment: Very awesome summarized answer in a nutshell.

Answer (score 1):

Flash Builder is better suited for user interface programming where the focus is creating, reading, updating, and deleting data. It provides you with layout and data access tools, and many more that would be extremely difficult (I'd like to say practically impossible) to achieve (and more importantly, maintain) in Flash Pro.

Flash Pro is more focused on creating and animating graphics. Your focus is the timeline, thus, what visually happens to each graphic object in which frame[s]. You create ActionScript code, most likely writing event handlers for frame events and any other visual-related manipulation.